# How to block all ports except 80, 443, 22, 3306 ports using firewalld?

Tags: linux, firewalld

How to filter all ports except 80, 443, 22, 3306 ports using firewalld on CentOS 7?

I searched unix.stackexchange.com, find this [about iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144605/etc-sysconfig-iptables-how-to-block-everything-except-for-port-80-and-22).

but how to block every port except special ports by firewalld?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: https://unixmen.com/iptables-vs-firewalld/

Comment: Updated my Post

Comment: @jsotola  your link do not provide the way to realize it.

Comment: 1/2 way down the page ... look for `Adding Port in Public Zone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS 7 uses `firewalld` by default.

If `firewalld` is enabled and running, then all ports are blocked by default unless they were enable at install (which is usually done with ssh which is port 22 unless it's set to run on another port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) or enabled by the person managing the system.

Start and enable the service:

```
systemctl start firewalld
systemctl enable firewalld
```

Open the ports:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=22/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp
```

Reload `firewalld`

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

To show the open ports:

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

Comment: firewall-cmd --permanent ---zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
 : The zone argument has 3 "-". It must be --zone=public instead of ---zone=public